# Load testing the JUnit test cases for Camel routes using JMeter

Tags: testing, junit, jmeter, apache-camel, routes

I am extending org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringTestSupport.CamelSpringTestSupport to write unit tests for the Camel routes; which are run as a part of maven build. Now I would like to load test them using JMeter. Any good pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you put the necessary jars in lib and test jar files should be placed in 
**jmeter/lib/junit** instead of /lib directory folder.

Read :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request

When using JUnit 4, classes don't need to extend TestCase, as you can see here:

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/junit/test/RerunTest.java

Comment: I have noticed the JUnit test cases which I have coded by extending org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringTestSupport are not being loaded into JUnitRequest sampler. So as to test I coded a JUnit test class extending junit.framework.TestCase, it successfully loaded it. Any good pointers here?

Comment: There are no errors in jmeter.log file, but I see setUp(), tearDown() method logs from the test cases that extend junit.framework.TestCase. I also read from the link you shared that says '1. rather than use Jmeter's test interface, it scans the jar files for classes extending junit's TestCase class. That includes any class or subclass.' So I believe that could be the reason JMeter is not supporting other test cases which are extending org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringTestSupport since this class does not extend junit.framework.TestCase

Comment: Do yoy use annotations in your test classes

Comment: Here are the imports and test class excerpt, sorry for no proper indentation: import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringTestSupport;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class RouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {...}

Comment: Update your question, I don't see any annotation

Comment: I am using <p>@Test</p> and <p>@Before</p> annotations

Comment: I updated answer. Do you put your Junit test jar in jmeter/lib/junit instead of /lib directory

Comment: Please update the Question showing some code, or open a bugzilla attaching a simple Test plan and simple class showing issue.